# Отправка письма через smtp C++

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-10, smtp, winsock

Искал реализацию для отправки писем через smtp, документации не нашел, пришлось по форумам бродить но нигде ничего дельного не было. Нашел тему на форуме http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread1020524... от 2012 года, вроде делал по аналогии, но так ничего и не добился.

Если коротко, вот код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#pragma comment (lib,"Ws2_32.lib") 
#include <windows.h> 
#include <winsock.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

WSADATA ws; 
SOCKET s; 
struct sockaddr_in addr; 
hostent* d_addr; 
char text[1024]; 

int main() 
{ 
// инициализируем сокеты 
if (FAILED(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1, 1), &ws))) 
{ 
printf("Error in WSAStartup(...)\n"); 
return 1; 
} 

// создаем сокет 
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
if (s == INVALID_SOCKET) 
{ 
printf("Error in socket(...)\n"); 
return 1; 
} 

// получаем адрес сервера 
d_addr = gethostbyname("smtp.gmail.com"); 
if (d_addr == NULL) 
{ 
printf("Error in gethostbyname(...)\n"); 
return 1; 
}; 

// заполняем параметры адреса 
addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)d_addr->h_addr); 
addr.sin_port = htons(465); 

// устанавливаем соединение 
if (SOCKET_ERROR == (connect(s, (sockaddr*)& addr, 
sizeof(addr)))) 
{ 
printf("Error in connect(...)\n"); 
return 1; 
} 

// ждем ответ от сервера 
recv(s, text, sizeof(text), 0); 
printf("recv - %s", text); 

// приветствуем сервер 
strcpy(text, "EHLO SSL\r\n"); 
send(s, text, strlen(text), 0); 
printf("send - %s", text); 

// ждем подтверждение от сервера 
recv(s, text, sizeof(text), 0); 
printf("recv - %s", text); 

// начинаем отправлять конверт состоящий из полей 
// MAIL FROM: и RCPT TO: После каждого поля ждем 
// подтверждение 
strcpy(text, "AUTH LOGIN\r\n"); 
send(s, text, strlen(text), 0); 
printf("send - %s", text); 

recv(s, text, sizeof(text), 0); 
printf("recv - %s", text); 
// сообщаем отправителя 
strcpy(text, "MAIL FROM: [email]sender@mail.ru[/email] "); 
send(s, text, strlen(text), 0); 
printf("send - %s", text); 

// ждем подтверждение от сервера 
recv(s, text, sizeof(text), 0); 
printf("recv - %s", text); 

// сообщаем получателя 
strcpy(text, "RCPT TO: [email]receiver@mtu-net.ru[/email] "); 
send(s, text, strlen(text), 0); 
printf("send - %s", text); 

// ждем подтверждение от сервера 
recv(s, text, sizeof(text), 0); 
printf("recv - %s", text); 

// подаем команду, что готовы начать передачу письма 
strcpy(text, "DATA\r\n"); 
send(s, text, strlen(text), 0); 
printf("send - %s", text); 

// ждем подтверждение от сервера 
recv(s, text, sizeof(text), 0); 
printf("recv - %s", text); 

// передаем заголовок 

// от кого письмо 
strcpy(text, "FROM: [email]sender@mail.ru[/email] "); 
send(s, text, strlen(text), 0); 
printf("send - %s", text); 

// кому письмо 
strcpy(text, "TO: [email]receiver@mtu-net.ru[/email] "); 
send(s, text, strlen(text), 0); 
printf("send - %s", text); 

// тема письма 
strcpy(text, "SUBJECT: test\r\n"); 
send(s, text, strlen(text), 0); 
printf("send - %s", text); 

// текст письма 
strcpy(text, "Hi!\nIt is a message for you\n"); 
send(s, text, strlen(text), 0); 
printf("send - %s", text); 

// говорим, что закончили 
strcpy(text, "\r\n.\r\n"); 
send(s, text, strlen(text), 0); 
printf("send - %s", text); 
recv(s, text, sizeof(text), 0); 
printf("recv - %s", text); 

// прощаемся с сервером 
strcpy(text, "QUIT"); 
send(s, text, strlen(text), 0); 
printf("send - %s", text); 

// закрываем сокет 
closesocket(s); 

return 0; 
}
```

Он вроде как рабочий, через 25 порт и 587 соединение проходит. Но на моменте запроса авторизации сервер выдает ошибку, что не используется шифрование. Как я понял, это из-за того, что я использую порт, который не поддерживает шифрование. По документации такой порт - 465, но когда я его ставлю, сервер долго соединяется и в итоге ничего не отвечает, т.е пустыми сообщениями, хотя вроде соединение есть.

Вот такая картина при 465 порте:

> recv - send - EHLO SSL  recv - EHLO SSL  send - AUTH LOGIN  recv -
>   AUTH LOGIN  send
>
> - MAIL FROM: sender@mail.ru recv - MAIL FROM: sender@mail.ru send - RCPT TO: receiver@mtu-net.ru recv - RCPT TO: receiver@mtu-net.ru send
> - DATA  recv - DATA  send - FROM: sender@mail.ru send - TO: receiver@mtu-net.ru send - SUBJECT: test  send - Hi!  It is a message
>     for you  send -  .  recv -  .  send - QUIT

Вот такая при других:

> recv - 220 smtp2o.mail.yandex.net ESMTP (Want to use Yandex.Mail for
>   your domain? Visit http://pdd.yandex.ru) send - EHLO SSL recv -
>   250-smtp2o.mail.yandex.net 250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING 250-SIZE
>   42991616 250-STARTTLS 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 250-DSN 250
>   ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES send - AUTH LOGIN recv - 530 5.7.7 Email sending
>   without SSL/TLS encryption is not allowed. Please see:
>   http://help.yandex.ru/mail/mail-clients/ssl.xml
>
> 250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES send - MAIL FROM: sender@mail.ru recv - MAIL
>   FROM: sender@mail.ru send - RCPT TO: receiver@mtu-net.ru recv - RCPT
>   TO: receiver@mtu-net.ru send - DATA recv - DATA send - FROM:
>   sender@mail.ru send - TO: receiver@mtu-net.ru send - SUBJECT: test
>   send - Hi! It is a message for you send - . recv - . send - QUIT

Не знаю, что делать, буду признателен, если поможете.

Comment: Надо устанавливать зашифрованное соединение через TLS

Comment: у Gmail  даже лет 8-9 назад не было возможности использовать smtp без шифрации, поэтому ваш вариант на сырых сокетах работать с gmail не будет (c mail ru в 2012 работал бы, возможно. с почтой от rambler у меня на  втором курсе точно получилось на сырых сокетах без шифрования  отправить сообщение).

Comment: возможно зашифровать соединение средствами языка? без дополнительных библиотек по типу curl`а

Comment: Можно и без curl, но тогда рекомендую установить библиотеку openSSL, в любом случае она Вам понадобится, даже если будете устанавливать curl, для поддержки протоколов шифрования он потребует openSSL.

Answer (score 1):

Советую воспользоваться библиотекой libcurl:
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/smtp-mail.html

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

/*
* For an SMTP example using the multi interface please see smtp-multi.c.
*/

/* The libcurl options want plain addresses, the viewable headers in the mail
* can very well get a full name as well.
*/
#define FROM_ADDR    "<sender@example.org>"
#define TO_ADDR      "<addressee@example.net>"
#define CC_ADDR      "<info@example.org>"

#define FROM_MAIL "Sender Person " FROM_ADDR
#define TO_MAIL   "A Receiver " TO_ADDR
#define CC_MAIL   "John CC Smith " CC_ADDR

static const char *payload_text[] = {
"Date: Mon, 29 Nov 2010 21:54:29 +1100\r\n",
"To: " TO_MAIL "\r\n",
"From: " FROM_MAIL "\r\n",
"Cc: " CC_MAIL "\r\n",
"Message-ID: <dcd7cb36-11db-487a-9f3a-e652a9458efd@"
"rfcpedant.example.org>\r\n",
"Subject: SMTP example message\r\n",
"\r\n", /* empty line to divide headers from body, see RFC5322 */
"The body of the message starts here.\r\n",
"\r\n",
"It could be a lot of lines, could be MIME encoded, whatever.\r\n",
"Check RFC5322.\r\n",
NULL
};

struct upload_status {
int lines_read;
};

static size_t payload_source(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
struct upload_status *upload_ctx = (struct upload_status *)userp;
const char *data;

if((size == 0) || (nmemb == 0) || ((size*nmemb) < 1)) {
    return 0;
}

data = payload_text[upload_ctx->lines_read];

if(data) {
    size_t len = strlen(data);
    memcpy(ptr, data, len);
    upload_ctx->lines_read++;

    return len;
}

return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res = CURLE_OK;
struct curl_slist *recipients = NULL;
struct upload_status upload_ctx;

upload_ctx.lines_read = 0;

curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
    /* This is the URL for your mailserver */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "smtp://mail.example.com");

    /* Note that this option isn't strictly required, omitting it will result
    * in libcurl sending the MAIL FROM command with empty sender data. All
    * autoresponses should have an empty reverse-path, and should be directed
    * to the address in the reverse-path which triggered them. Otherwise,
    * they could cause an endless loop. See RFC 5321 Section 4.5.5 for more
    * details.
    */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM, FROM_ADDR);

    /* Add two recipients, in this particular case they correspond to the
    * To: and Cc: addressees in the header, but they could be any kind of
    * recipient. */
    recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients, TO_ADDR);
    recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients, CC_ADDR);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT, recipients);

    /* We're using a callback function to specify the payload (the headers and
    * body of the message). You could just use the CURLOPT_READDATA option to
    * specify a FILE pointer to read from. */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, payload_source);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, &upload_ctx);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);

    /* Send the message */
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    /* Check for errors */
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
    fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
            curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* Free the list of recipients */
    curl_slist_free_all(recipients);

    /* curl won't send the QUIT command until you call cleanup, so you should
    * be able to re-use this connection for additional messages (setting
    * CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM and CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT as required, and calling
    * curl_easy_perform() again. It may not be a good idea to keep the
    * connection open for a very long time though (more than a few minutes
    * may result in the server timing out the connection), and you do want to
    * clean up in the end.
    */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}

return (int)res;
}
```